# not able to navigate to root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Protocol method not being called. I am using pop over controller. i get a nil delegate and the method in Time table view controller not being called. Where am i going wrong. I am new to this protocol. below is my code.. i just posted only main code removing all the other useless code... i just want to navigate from TimeTable view controller to Root view controller on selection of a button from PopOverView controller

```
TimetableView Controller.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NotesandReminders.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "PopOverViewController.h"

@class PopOverViewController;

@interface TimeTableViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,TestProtocol>


@property(nonatomic,strong)PopOverViewController *testViewController;






Timetable view controller.m


@interface TimeTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation TimeTableViewController



@synthesize testViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.testViewController=[[PopOverViewController alloc]init];

    testViewController.delegate=self;
 }

-(void)LogOut
{

 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}




POPOVER VIEW CONTROLLER.H

@protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void)LogOut;

@end


POP OVER VIEW CONTROLLER.H
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TimeTableViewController.h"


@class TimeTableViewController;
@interface PopOverViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    id<TestProtocol>delegate;
}

- (IBAction)out:(id)sender;


@property(nonatomic,strong)TimeTableViewController *testTimeTableViewController;

@property(nonatomic,strong)UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property(retain) id<TestProtocol>delegate;


@end




POP OVER VIEW CONTROLLER.M 

#import "PopOverViewController.h"

@interface PopOverViewController ()

@end

@implementation PopOverViewController

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize popoverController,testTimeTableViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{



    self.delegate=testTimeTableViewController;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



- (IBAction)out:(id)sender {
   self.TimeObj=[[TimeTableViewController alloc]init];
[self.TimeObj Signout];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be with the `viewDidLoad` method, when you assign `self.delegate=testTimeTableViewController;`, because `testTimeTableViewController` was never initialized.

Since you are assigning the delegate when you create the view controller, you should not assign it again.

Also, you must not `retain` the delegate, use a `weak` reference instead.